# How to output the shortest path in Floyd-Warshall algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, floyd-warshall

I'm trying to implement Floyd-Warshall algorithm (all pairs shortest path). In the code below, when I enter some numbers, it gives the last number as input. I know the code is not complete.

Now what should I do to print shortest paths for each i and j? Or what do you suggest to me to do to complete this code. Thanks.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string ab = textBox11.Text;
    int matrixDimention = Convert.ToInt32(ab);
    int[,] intValues = new int[matrixDimention, matrixDimention];
    string[] splitValues = textBox9.Text.Split(',');
    for (int i = 0; i < splitValues.Length; i++)
        intValues[i / (matrixDimention), i % (matrixDimention)] =    Convert.ToInt32(splitValues[i]);
    string displayString = "";
    for (int inner = 0; inner < intValues.GetLength(0); inner++)
    {
        for (int outer = 0; outer < intValues.GetLength(0); outer++)
            displayString += String.Format("{0}\t", intValues[inner, outer]);
        displayString += Environment.NewLine;
    }
    int n = (int)Math.Pow(matrixDimention, 2);
    string strn = n.ToString();

    MessageBox.Show("matrix"+strn+ "in" + strn + "is\n\n\n" +displayString);
////before this line i wrote the codes to get the numbers that user enter in textbox and put it in an 2d array
    for (int k = 1; k < n+1; k++)

        for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)

            for (int j = 1; j < n+1; j++)

                if (intValues[i, j] > intValues[i, k] + intValues[k, j])
                {
                    intValues[i, j] = intValues[i, k] + intValues[k, j];
                    string str_intvalues = intValues[i, j].ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Shortest Path from i to j is: " + str_intvalues);

                }
                else
                {
                    string str_intvalues = intValues[i, j].ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Shortest Path from i to j is: " + str_intvalues);
                }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using Floyd algorithm, it saves only the shortest distance from node i to node j of your graph. So, you can also save the path to nodes. How to do it?

one of the ways to implement it - is to save the parent (the node, which is a previous node for current node in the path) node. You are to make another matrix, which will contain paths. It could look like this:

```
int[,] pathS = new int[matrixDimention, matrixDimention];
for (int i = 0; i < splitValues.Length; i++){
    intValues[i / (matrixDimention), i % (matrixDimention)] = Convert.ToInt32(splitValues[i]);
    pathS[i / (matrixDimention), i % (matrixDimention)] = -1;    
}
.....
for (int k = 1; k < n+1; k++)
    for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j < n+1; j++)
            if (intValues[i, j] > intValues[i, k] + intValues[k, j]){                
                intValues[i, j] = intValues[i, k] + intValues[k, j];
                pathS[i,j] = k;
                string str_intvalues = intValues[i, j].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Shortest Path from i to j is: " + str_intvalues);
            }
            else{                
                string str_intvalues = intValues[i, j].ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Shortest Path from i to j is: " + str_intvalues);
            }
```

Now you have additional pathS array, which contains intermidiate paths between nodes i and j. For better understandning you should consider, that pathS[i,j] is a node between this two nodes (e.g. i -> [k] -> j). But your path could be longer, than 3 nodes (that's why I wrote node k in [] braces). So, now you have to check path between i and k - pathS[i,k] and path between k and j - pathS[k,j]. And do the same recursively, until pathS between some i and j equals to "-1".

Answer (score 9):

To be on a same page, let me show you the Floyd-Warshall algorithm first:

Let us have a graph, described by matrix `D`, where `D[i][j]` is the length of edge `(i -> j)` *(from graph's vertex with index `i` to the vertex with index `j`)*.

Matrix `D` has the size of `N * N`, where `N` is total number of vertices in graph, because we can reach the maximum of paths by connecting each graph's vertex to each other.

Also we'll need matrix `R`, where we will store shortest paths (`R[i][j]` contains the index of a next vertex in the shortest path, starting at vertex `i` and ending at vertex `j`).

Matrix `R` has the same size as `D`.

The Floyd-Warshall algorithm performs these steps:

1. initialize the matrix of all the paths between any two pairs or vertices in a graph with the edge's end vertex *(this is important, since this value will be used for path reconstruction)*
2. for each pair of connected vertices *(read: for each edge `(u -> v)`)*, `u` and `v`, find the vertex, which forms shortest path between them: if the vertex `k` defines two valid edges `(u -> k)` and `(k -> v)` *(if they are present in the graph)*, which are together shorter than path `(u -> v)`, then assume the shortest path between `u` and `v` lies through `k`; set the shortest pivot point in matrix `R` for edge `(u -> v)` to be the corresponding pivot point for edge `(u -> k)`

Now that we are on a same page with definitions, algorithm can be implemented like this:

```
// Initialise the routes matrix R
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int t = 0; t < N; t++) {
        R[i][t] = t;
    }
}

// Floyd-Warshall algorithm:
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    for (int u = 0; u < N; u++) {
        for (int v = 0; v < N; v++) {
            if (D[u, v] > D[u, k] + D[k, v]) {
                D[u, v] = D[u, k] + D[k, v];
                R[u, v] = R[u, k];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But how do we read the matrix `D`?

Let us have a graph:

[image: Graph]

> In GraphViz it would be described as follows:
>
> ```
> digraph G {
>     0->2 [label = "1"];
>     2->3 [label = "5"];
>     3->1 [label = "2"];
>     1->2 [label = "6"];
>     1->0 [label = "7"];
> }
> ```

We first create a two-dimensional array of size `4` *(since there are exactly `4` vertices in our graph)*.

We initialize its main diagonal *(the items, whose indices are equal, for ex. `G[0, 0]`, `G[1, 1]`, etc.)* with zeros, because
the shortest path from vertex to itself has the length `0` and the other elements with a very large number *(to indicate there is no edge or an infinitely long edge between them)*. The defined elements, corresponding to graph's edges, we fill with edges' lengths:

```
int N = 4;
int[,] D = new int[N, N];

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (int t = 0; t < N; t++) {
        if (i == t) {
            D[i, t] = 0;
        } else {
            D[i, t] = 9999;
        }
    }
}

D[0, 2] = 1;
D[1, 0] = 7;
D[1, 2] = 6;
D[2, 3] = 5;
D[3, 1] = 2;
```

After the algorithm run, the matrix `R` will be filled with vertices' indices, describing shortest paths between them. In order to reconstruct the path from vertex `u` to vertex `v`, you need follow the elements of matrix `R`:

```
List<Int32> Path = new List<Int32>();

while (start != end)
{
    Path.Add(start);

    start = R[start, end];
}

Path.Add(end);
```

The whole code could be wrapped in a couple of methods:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class FloydWarshallPathFinder {
    private int N;
    private int[,] D;
    private int[,] R;

    public FloydWarshallPathFinder(int NumberOfVertices, int[,] EdgesLengths) {
        N = NumberOfVertices;
        D = EdgesLengths;
        R = null;
    }

    public int[,] FindAllPaths() {
        R = new int[N, N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < N; t++)
            {
                R[i, t] = t;
            }
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
        {
            for (int v = 0; v < N; v++)
            {
                for (int u = 0; u < N; u++)
                {
                    if (D[u, k] + D[k, v] < D[u, v])
                    {
                        D[u, v] = D[u, k] + D[k, v];
                        R[u, v] = R[u, k];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return R;
    }

    public List<Int32> FindShortestPath(int start, int end) {
        if (R == null) {
            FindAllPaths();
        }

        List<Int32> Path = new List<Int32>();

        while (start != end)
        {
            Path.Add(start);

            start = R[start, end];
        }

        Path.Add(end);

        return Path;
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int N = 4;
        int[,] D = new int[N, N];

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int t = 0; t < N; t++) {
                if (i == t) {
                    D[i, t] = 0;
                } else {
                    D[i, t] = 9999;
                }
            }
        }

        D[0, 2] = 1;
        D[1, 0] = 7;
        D[1, 2] = 6;
        D[2, 3] = 5;
        D[3, 1] = 2;

        FloydWarshallPathFinder pathFinder = new FloydWarshallPathFinder(N, D);

        int start = 0;
        int end = 1;

        Console.WriteLine("Path: {0}", String.Join(" -> ", pathFinder.FindShortestPath(start, end).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

You can read 'bout this algorithm on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) and get some data structures generated automatically [here](http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/)